# Trying to remove Ubuntu-desktop with tasksel returns "aptitude failed"

Tags: desktop-environments, aptitude, tasksel

I am following [this](http://www.darrinhodges.com/converting-ubuntu-12-04-lts-desktop-to-server/) guide trying to turn my Ubuntu-desktop-installation into Ubuntu-server.

However, I am having problems already in step 2. Using tasksel to remove/install anything returns with:

> tasksel: aptitude failed (100)

I've Googled around and read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185645/why-does-tasksel-give-an-aptitude-failed-error) question (it was the first thing I tried), but nothing suggested works.

I am running 12.04.

Afraid I do now have much more information than that. If anyone could point me in the direction of an error-log that I could look into I can supply with further info, but I have not found anything of interest in them yet.

Comment: Was there any other error output, or was it just that error?  It may have failed if you have not done `sudo apt-get update` by hand, or if `aptitude` is not installed

Comment: @ThomasW. I've done `apt-get update` and it works like it should. Also installing anything using `apt-get` works. When  using `tasksel` only that error is returned. I see the "pink"-view with the download-bar for a few seconds before it jumps out again. No idea what's wrong.

Comment: There's no way to diagnose this issue, then, unless tasksel has a log that its keeping somewhere.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue on 14.04 and managed to solve it. The reason was some broken dependencies. In my case it was Java package so I removed it and then reinstalled after running tasksel.

A one way to find broken dependency is to try to run `apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop^` and see whether it will complain about unsatisfied dependencies or just list packages to remove. **Make sure to select No and don't actually remove any packages with this command. It may ruin your system**

Answer (score 3):

I am running **14.04**. I've got this error, then I installed **default-jre** and then I could remove **ubuntu-desktop** by **tasksel**.